# Statement invalid while rendering json in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5.2, railsapps

for my snippet below for rendering the json

```
def show
   @product = Product.find(params[:id])
      render json: @product.to_json(:include => { :items => { :only => [:id, 
:description] }}) 
end
```

While rendering the json for has many attributes model I am getting invalid statement as follows:

```
(Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'items.product_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `items`.* FROM `items` WHERE `items`.`product_id` = 1):
```

While I have a column called products_id for the foreign key instead of product_id. I need to throw statement as products_id without changing the column name in database.

Comment: Please show your `Product` and `Item` models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Product model you should have something like `has_many :items`. This line creates an association with default foreign key `product_id`. To change foreign key you need to change this line to `has_many :items, foreign_key: :products_id`.

Comment: Since we're speculating without seeing the actual model code - are you sure that's all? What about `belongs_to` association in `Item` model?

Comment: Pretty sure it will fix the problem with the unknown column and will allow OP to render this JSON. `belongs_to` is another issue.